# Angular Bootstrap tour 'end tour' when clicked stops the tour for good

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-tour

I have a tour currently running on my site, but it doesn't seem to actually keep track of if the user has clicked End Tour. Meaning that if they click it once, it ends the tour, but then when they revisit the page, the tour will automatically start again as though it's the first time they've landed on that page.

I follow the code on:  https://github.com/benmarch/angular-bootstrap-tour

Comment: You should save a flag in your database or local storage when the tour is complete, using the `on-end` attribute to specify the function which saves the flag. Then on page load, you can access the value of the flag and show the tour or not based on the state of the flag, e.g. using `ng-if`.

Comment: i tried on this but when click on next step for multipage everytime call goes into ' on-end' attributes function.So if I set value in local storage it ends the tour on click of next button also.